# .NET MVC PagedListPager equivalent in Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, pagination, webforms

I am new to web forms and I was given a task of converting an .NET MVC app to a Web Forms app.

I am stuck in a line of code for the pagination.

I need  a pagination of Integers when I click on each number I get redirected to a link Example.com/orders?page=X

I was able to this in MVC using this line of code.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(MyIntegersList, page => Url.Action("orders",
    new {page}))
```

But I have no clue how to do this in Web Forms.

Please help !

Comment: Indeed, this is the first time I hear someone wants to go from MVC to Web Forms and not the other way around! (don't get me wrong, I like Web Forms more than MVC) :)

Comment: About paging, how you do it depends on the server control(s) you're using. For example, the GridView allows for paging as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/sorting-paging-and-filtering-data. So, more details and/or sample code is needed in order to answer your question.

Comment: It's my first time too, but you really can't say no if all your co-workers are familiar with web forms only. I will try to use your link if I don't find any way easier, as you can see, with MVC I did it with one line of code so i am looking for the same thing in web forms.